# Are questions about use of electronics test equipment off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few instances where questions are asked about the use of electronics ***test equipment*** and close votes accumulate for being about the "use of electronics devices rather than electronics design."

Shouldn't questions about the use of electronics test equipment such as multimeters, oscilloscopes, function generators, and so on, be generally *on-topic*?

Consider this question: [Fluke 8508A reporting back before settling](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/103313/2028). I'm not saying it's a *great* question, but isn't the scope of the site more than just circuit design? While the question pretty much requires familiarity with Fluke instrumentation (somewhat narrow), isn't it a common problem that could be encountered in the course of electronics design?

I would only vote to close such a question if it was obvious that the OP was trying to use test equipment for something clearly outside the scope of EE work. (Like "How do I make an oscilloscope show some cool stuff for my sci-fi movie?")

Answer (score 20):

I'd say that questions regarding the use of equipment are on-topic, and I don't see any reason to think otherwise.

Another matter are recommendations for such equipment (i.e. *Where do I find a cheap multimeter?*).

Comment: Although if someone were to ask that question "_Where do I find a cheap multimeter_", they would probably get the answer of "everywhere and anywhere" from about 5 people before the question got deleted :-)